# Break outside of Loop python

Tags: python

I have following code in python but it's saying break outside of loop, when clearly its within the if statement in the loop

```
import json
c=0
with open("test.json") as json_file:
        c+=1
        if(c>10):
                break
        json_data = json.load(json_file)
        print(json_data)
```

Comment: When did `if` become a loop?

Comment: What loop? `with` and `if` are not loops.

Answer (score 7):

There's no loop. `with` is not a loop, neither is `if`.

Looks like you're missing your `for` statement.

Also, a more pythonic way of doing things:

```
import json
import itertools

with open('test.json') as json_file:
    for _ in itertools.repeat(None, 10):
        json_data = json.load(json_file)
        print(json_data)
```

or the simpler:

```
import json

with open('test.json') as json_file:
    for _ in xrange(10):
        json_data = json.load(json_file)
        print(json_data)
```

Comment: *There's no loop. with is not a loop, neither is if.* ... Man! Have to upvote only for these words !!! KIU :)